# jquery select index from data and show sql content

Tags: jquery, mysql, database

i dont know how can I make it work. I explain it.

I have some html code with jquery script.

html

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a class="0" href="#">aparamenta modular</a></h3>
    <div>
    <div class="cat_content_ex">
        t&eacute;rmicos, diferenciales, etc ...
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a class="1" href="#">iluminaci&oacute;n</a></h3>
    <div>
    <div class="cat_content_ex">
        luminarias std y sistemas de LED, etc ...
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('h3 > a').live('click', function(){
        var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
        alert ( currentClass, 'alert window');
        if(currentClass == '0') {
            <?php
                include "./connection_catalogs.php";                
                $SQL = "SELECT * FROM first_table";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    $('#target').html($(<?php echo "<p class='ctg_fab'>" .$row['fabricante']. " : " .$row['titulo']. " : <a href='" .$row['url']. "'>descarga</a> : tipo - " .$row['filetype']. "</p>";?>)); 
                }
        } else if(ctg == '1') {
            <?php
                include "./connection_catalogs.php";                
                $SQL = "SELECT * FROM second_table";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    $('#target').html($(<?php echo "<p class='ctg_fab'>" .$row['fabricante']. " : " .$row['titulo']. " : <a href='" .$row['url']. "'>descarga</a> : tipo - " .$row['filetype']. "</p>";?>)); 
                }
                }
            ?>
        }
});
</script>
```

user click in first header of accordion and show the content for sql table named 'first_table' by executing `echo "<p class='ctg_fab'>" .$row['fabricante']. " : " .$row['titulo']. " : <a href='" .$row['url']. "'>descarga</a> : tipo - " .$row['filetype']. "</p>";`

user click in second header of accordion and show the content for sql table named 'second_table' by executing `echo "<p class='ctg_fab'>" .$row['fabricante']. " : " .$row['titulo']. " : <a href='" .$row['url']. "'>descarga</a> : tipo - " .$row['filetype']. "</p>";`

Comment: Could you please try to clarify, what is the question?

Comment: yes I do. the question is that doesn't work. i'd like the user to click in each accordion's header and depending of which header has clicked it'll show each content from sql table or another.

Comment: How/where do you want the content to be shown after the user has clicked the `h3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#accordion.h3')` selects an element with `id="accordion" class="h3"`.

Change it to `$('#accordion > h3')` which selects an `<h3>` element that has a parent element with `id="accordion"`.

Comment: yes its ok but script dont return neither alert nor the sql data ... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    document.write(<?php echo "<p class='ctg_fab'>" .$row['fabricante']. " : " .$row['titulo']. " : <a href='" .$row['url']. "'>descarga</a> : tipo - " .$row['filetype']. "</p>";?>) 
}
```

Comment: dont know why should i use document.write function ...?

Comment: is it working or not? because you mixed php and javascript up and the result is, both concepts are mixed up (confusing you). php's echo is only print the result in to the javascript code, but not in the document/html. and the document.write is javascipt's function to show it in the document. anyway, try to make your codes simpler and easier to read so the confusion wont happen again :)

Answer (score 0):

finally i made in ajax.

calling a jscript function when user click in a link

html

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a onClick= MuestraCatalogo(1) href="#">aparamenta modular</a></h3>
    <div>
    <div class="cat_content_ex">
        t&eacute;rmicos, diferenciales, etc ...
    </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a onClick= MuestraCatalogo(2) href="#">iluminaci&oacute;n</a></h3>
    <div>
    <div class="cat_content_ex">
        luminarias std y sistemas de LED, etc ...
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

script

```
function MuestraCatalogo(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("cat_rcpt").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("cat_rcpt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","auth/peticion_catalogo.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

peticion_catalogo.php

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    include "../connection_catalogs.php";
    if($q == 1){
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM aparamenta_modular";
    } else if($q == 2){
            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM control_industrial";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    echo "<table class='ctgPage'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='ctgCabPage' style='width:150px'>FABRICANTE</td>";
    echo "<td class='ctgCabPage' style='width:300px'>CAT&Aacute;LOGO</td>";
    echo "<td colspan='2' class='ctgCabPage' style='width:150px'>ENLACE</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td class='ctgCabData' style='width:150px'>" .$row['fabricante']. "</td>";
        echo "<td class='ctgCabData' style='width:300px'>" .$row['titulo']. "</td>";
        if($row['filetype']=="pdf") {
            $url_icon = "http://www.domain.com/img/pdf.png";
        } else if($row['filetype']=="xls") {
            $url_icon = "http://www.domain.com/img/xls.png";
        } else if($row['filetype']=="rar") {
            $url_icon = "http://www.domain.com/img/rar.png";
        } 
        echo "<td colspan='2' class='ctgCabData' style='width:150px'><a href='" .$row['url']. "'><img src='http://www.domain.com/img/download.png' alt='descarga'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='" .$url. "' alt='type'></td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($con);  
?>
```